# Collection.find({key: any_value in an array }) matching multiple values with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi, I have a "Tweets" Schema, which has a key of "author" and I would like to find all tweets whose author is any value in an array of people. For instance,

if I could do something like:

let people = ['josh','bob','tim'];

```
Tweet.find({ author: [people] }).then((tweets) => {
      // tweets = all tweets that have any of the following authors: josh, bob, or time
})
```

Essentially, is there a mongoose specific way to do:

```
people.forEach((person)=> {
   Tweet.find({ author: person})
})
```

Also note that the 'people' array changes per user that is logged in/session user.

Comment: also  remember "people.forEach((person)=> {
   Tweet.find.... " is a worst idea

Comment: hm, why would you say that is the worst idea?

Comment: first: increase size of array reduce performance , second: calling async function inside loop does not work, althoght you can do second. by map of promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tweet.find({ author: {$in:  people }},(err,tweets)=>{
      //code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple try

```
 Tweet.find({ 
// sorry it should be in
    author: {$in:  [people] }
 })
 .then((tweets) => {
})
```